# MySql Composite Foreign Key Referncing same column

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am attempting to create a **composite foreign** key in **MySQL** however both fields are referencing the same column in another table. I am not sure if this is the accurate approach since the sql is not executing. Under is the SQL statement

**SQL**

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT `comp_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`a_id` , `b_id` )
    REFERENCES `tabelB` (`p_id` , `p_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**Error**

```
MySQL Database Error: Can't create table 'sep.#sql-984_8' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: It isn't the pair of columns `a_id, b_id` referencing a _pair_ of `p_id`, but instead they each reference `p_id` individually. You need _two_ `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, not a composite one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by individually applying constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `comp_fk`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `tabelB`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test2` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `tabelB`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```